# GUID Generation

Tags: vb6, guid

When is the GUID generated for a VB6 DLL? I believe it is generated automatically when a DLL is registered.  However, I have found references online to APIs that allow you to generate GUIDs in code.

Answer (score 1):

Interface, type, and class GUIDs are created by the compiler.  But GUIDs are used for lots of things in Windows besides component registration, including unique ID values for rows in database tables.

Comment: If I compile a VB6 program (producing a DLL) and compile the same VB6 program again (producing a second DLL), will they both have separate GUIDs

Comment: Read the documentation on maintaining binary compatibility.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733715(VS.60).aspx is one possible starting point.